# golang initialize member with struct itself for sync.Mutex and sync.Cond

Tags: go, struct

Here is go code:

```
type someThing struct {
    sync.Mutex
    cv      *sync.Cond
    num     int
}

func NewSomething() *someThing {
    // how do you do this ?
    return &someThing{cv:sync.NewCond(sync.Mutex)}
}
```

This code fails to compile:

```
sync.Mutex (type) is not an expression
```

So basically the question is how to refer to the struct itself (because it has an embedded member sync.Mutex) while initializing it ? (c++ has *this*, for example).

Comment: Typical for Go: Write several lines, each lines doing one thing instead of one monster line doing everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new instance first, and then refer to the embedded field:

```
type SomeThing struct {
    sync.Mutex
    cv  *sync.Cond
    num int
}

func NewSomething() *SomeThing {
    st := &SomeThing{}
    st.cv = sync.NewCond(&st.Mutex)
    return st
}
```

GoPlay here: https://play.golang.org/p/BlnHMi1EKT

Comment: I guess I was looking for a way to do it in a single line, but looks like there isnt a way.